# Julia, Gumbo, Webscraping

Tags: julia, gumbo

I have scraped some data from a website and when i try to pass this data to array i got this message:

```
LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type HTMLText to an object of type Int64
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? Or even better, a distilled minimal version that produces the error?

Comment: Wildly guessing, I'd say that you might need a `parse(Int64, obj)`, where `obj` is the `HTMLText` object, somewhere.

Comment: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching parse(::Type{Int64}, ::HTMLText)
Closest candidates are:
  parse(::Type{T}, !Matched::AbstractChar; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:41
  parse(::Type{T}, !Matched::AbstractString; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:238
  parse(::Type{T}, !Matched::AbstractString; kwargs...) where T<:Real at parse.jl:376
in expression starting at C:\Users\Office\.atom\packages\uber-juno\testing.jl:17
top-level scope at testing.jl:19

Comment: using HTTP
using Gumbo
using Cascadia
using DataFrames

Base_Url="https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/A"
Active_Url=Base_Url
println(Active_Url)
h=HTTP.request("GET",Active_Url)
html=parsehtml(String(h))

From_Website=eachmatch(sel".bl_12",html.root)
#println(From_Website)
#println(From_Website[5][1])
i=5
lst=[]
while i>=1
    company_Nam=From_Website[i][1]
    company_Name=parse(Int64,company_Nam)
    push!(company_Name,lst)
end
print(lst)

Comment: Actually, i need to scrape data from https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/A and push to array then print